# Uploading file with latin characters such as á,é,í,ó,ú and ñ in Codeigniter

Tags: php, file, codeigniter, upload

Hi I'm having problems with the file uploading in CodeIgniter with files that have latin characters, when I upload them the name that I echo  is correctly shown but in the folder where I upload the file the name changes, for example I have this File:

```
"Tour al Volcán del Totumo y a los Manglares.docx"
```

When I echo the name it's shown like that but in the folder where the file is stored is shown like:

```
"Tour al VolcÃ¡n del Totumo y a los Manglares.docx"
```

I've looked everywhere and I haven't been able so solve this, also I have made configurations such as the utf-8 charset and all that stuff.

Comment: Where have you made those configurations?

Comment: In the config file of Codeigniter, I added $config['charset'] = 'UTF-8';
is there something else I need to do?

Comment: Yup, see [UTF-8 all the way through](http://stackoverflow.com/q/279170) for some generic advice (And Evert's excellent summary below of course)

Answer (score 1):

Files in folders are also shown in a specific character encoding. Which encoding that is, depends on the operating system.

Depending on the operating system, multiple bugs are possible.

**On linux**: Things are stored as UTF-8, but whatever you are using to view the folder (GUI, terminal, sftp client, ftp client, whatever) is set to default to something like latin-1 / ISO-8559-1 and showing it incorrectly, even though the files are correctly stored.

**On Mac:** Files are somehow being double-UTF-8 encoded in your application. This means the filename was already in UTF-8, and you are calling utf8_encode on the string again (which is bad!)

**On windows:** PHP only supports the ANSI-filesystem api on windows. There is literally no way (without using COM) to store files with unicode filenames, because the input string is always treated as if it was CP-1252, and converted to UTF-8. If the characters you are using all exist in CP-1252, you can convert your UTF-8 input to CP-1252 by using iconv or mb_convert_encoding.

More information: http://evertpot.com/filesystem-encoding-and-php (my blog)